# PHPMailer "Language string failed to load: tls"

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp, localhost

Não estou conseguindo enviar e-mail pelo PHPMailer 5.1, usei a seguinte classe:

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');

class Mailer extends PHPMailer 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->IsSMTP(true);
        $this->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $this->Host = 'mail.example.com.br'; // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
        $this->Port = 465;
        $this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->Username = 'script@example.com.br'; // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
        $this->Password = 's5njsd12efasc4';

        $this->IsHTML(true);
        $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $this->From = "script@example.com.br"; // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
        $this->FromName = "Example"; // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
    }
}
```

Estou usando da seguinte forma:

```php
    $mail = new Mailer;
    $mail->Subject = "Alerta";
    $mail->MsgHTML('teste');
    $mail->AddAddress('example@gmail.com'); // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
    $mail->AddBCC("example@example.com.br"); // Dados fictícios apenas para demonstração
    $mail->Send();
```

Resulta sempre em: `Language string failed to load: tls`

Já testei comentando algumas linhas:

Tentativa 1:

```php
// $this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Resulta em:
`SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

Tentativa 2:

```php
// $this->SMTPAuth = true;
// $this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Resulta em:
`The following From address failed: (meuemail@meuhost.com.br)`

Tentativa 3:

```php
// $this->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Resulta em:
`Language string failed to load: tls`

Tentativa 4:

```php
$this->Port = 25;
```

Resulta em:
`SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.`

Penso que não influencia em nada, mas só pra deixar claro estou usando local.

Se puder me ajudar serei eternamente grato :)

**ATUALIZAÇÂO 29/04/2020**

Também fiz teste com o PHPMailer 5.2.16, resultou em branco, é como se tivesse enviado o e-mail, porém não enviou, pois não chegou e-mail nenhum no meu correio eletrônico. Então inseri alguns `echo` nos erros da classe `class.phpmailer.php` e encontrei o seguinte erro:

```php
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Atualizei o PHPMailer pra a versão mais recente (6.1) via `composer.json`, conforme as [dicas](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), ativei o modo o debug `$this->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`, o resultado agora está sendo:

```php
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-04-29 14:09:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.100.10
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-04-29 14:09:11 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para o PHPMailer 6.1 foi encontrada:
Verifiquei se havia algum serviço sendo executado na porta SMTP 465, e não retornou 220 conforme as [dicas](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#check-its-a-mail-server), então tentei `$this->Port = 587;` e funcionou! :)